# Why does a named IIFE result in a ReferenceError outiside of it?

Tags: javascript, iife

Why did I get *“`ReferenceError`: `Person` is not defined”* for the following code?

```js
(function Person() {
  console.log('Hi');
}());
console.log(Person);
```

Since function `Person` is run, it is first created. However, I cannot explain why it is not then recognized. My only thought is that IIFE ignores the name they are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because the name of a function created by a function *expression* is not added to the scope the expression is in. (It *is* in-scope within the function body, so the name isn't just ignored.) A function *declaration* creates the name in the scope where it appears, but not a named function expression. That's just how JavaScript is defined.

If it's important that you stick to using an expression rather than a function declaration (for instance, because expressions are done in the step-by-step processing of the code, whereas declarations are done earlier), you can do it with a variable:

```
var Person = function Person() {
    console.log('Hi');
};
Person();
console.log(Person);
```

And that gets more concise with ES6, because in ES6 you can name a function without using a named function expression:

```
var Person = function() {
    console.log('Hi');
};
Person();
console.log(Person);
```

In ES5, that function wouldn't have a name (except many JavaScript engines gave it one anyway). In ES6, that function *does* have a name, which is taken from the variable.

Language designers don't necessarily need a "why" for decisions like not putting the name in scope, but it makes sense when you think of doing things like this:

```
// ES5 and earlier
var x = {
    foo: function foo() { /* ... */ },
    bar: function bar() { /* ... */ },
    baz: function baz() { /* ... */ }
};
```

It probably makes sense that the above adds `x` to the scope, but not `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.

Answer (score 7):

Named function expressions only create a variable matching their name *within their own scope*.

```js
(function Person() {
  // Person is in scope here
  console.log(Person);
}());
// Person is out of scope here
console.log(Person);
```

You need a function declaration to create a variable in the current scope. Function declarations can not be IIFEs.

If you need to create a function which you can call multiple times *and* call it immediately, then you need to do it in two steps:

```
function Person() {
  console.log('Hi');
}
Person();
```