# Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) use case in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iife

I get that IIFE's are used to prevent polluting the global name space. What I do not understand is that assuming that you have a variable that shares the same name, if you were to declare a variable using the key word `var` inside of a given function, wouldn't it not matter when the function was invoked at run time?
I'm probably making it sound more complicated than it is but look at the code blocks below:

Example 1: Without IIFE

```js
var firstName = "eugene";

function name(){
  var firstName = "bobby";
  console.log(firstName); 
}
name(); //bobby

console.log(firstName); //eugene
```

Example 2: Using IIFE

```js
var firstName = "eugene";

(function(){
  var firstName = "bobby";
  console.log(firstName);
})();

console.log(firstName);
```

Example 2 outputs essentially the same thing. What is the point of using IIFE's if it's going to out put the same thing?

Comment: There are many examples of this question already on stack.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317998/immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife-vs-not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between a named IIFE and calling a name function immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15688420/1048572)

Comment: it's... just a function that gets called immedaitely. Why does it need to have a point? it do what it do.

Comment: @SoEzPz I've taken a look at your suggestion  and a whole lot of other questions similar to this. It still didn't answer my question. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the IIFE, which could (should - although [the name doesn't hurt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32678200/1048572)) also have been written as

```
(function () {
//       ^ anonymous
  var firstName = "bobby";
  console.log(firstName);
})();
```

is to not introduce the `name` in the global scope. In your first example, you could have invoked `name()` twice or as often as you wanted.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score -1):

If the function is non IIFE you must call the function , if it a IIFE function no need to the call the function It executes immediately after it’s created.

Comment: but... by definition, an iife is... called... that's not a difference.